# "for physics envy" = for envy of physicists

Tags: expressions, meaning-in-context

My grammar QA doesn't let the following quote 'pass' (*italized* phrase ):

> "The illusion of objectivity gains in strength through distance. Biologists, psychologists and social scientists are notorious *for physics envy*, seeing physics as far more objective and precise than their own rather messy fields, where there is so much uncertainty."

its from "The Science Delusion" by Rupert Sheldrake.

It seems it says that say social scientists envy physicists because physics science they regard as much more precise and objective than their own science. However I doubt whether it can be correctly expressed as 'for physics envy' unless it's kinda idiomatic expression what I haven't find in the dictionaries I use.

Comment: Wikipedia actually has an article on _physics envy_.

Comment: You may be using 'physicians' to mean physicists.

Comment: Vlad and @Yosef, By the time I got here, "physicists" was in the title, so I went ahead and changed it in the body.

Comment: "xxx envy" is an idiom.

Answer (score 1):

Dictionaries aren't, in my experience, much use at generic idiomatic expressions.

"Physics" here is a noun being used as an adjective; this is very common in idiomatic English. "Physics envy" is therefore *envy of physics* (that is, envy of the field of physics, which is more or less equivalent to the "envy of physicists" you suggest).

Comment: 'Physics envy' is at least a collocation if not a compound noun, but one has to be careful about assuming productivity in these areas. 'Chemistry envy' is not much used, and I've found 1 Google hit for 'quantum mechanics envy' and not many more for 'cosmology envy'. You can guess how many relevant hits for 'meteorology envy'.

Comment: The fact that "physics envy" is common enough to have its Wikipedia article, and that the others aren't, doesn't change where the phrase came from. It came from using the noun "physics" as an adjective, just as "baby clothes" uses the noun "baby" as an adjective to describe the type of clothes.

Comment: I'm pointing out that one can't use 'physics' say idiomatically before any non-irrelevant noun. 'Physics exam', 'physics lesson', 'physics department' , 'physics envy' ... but not 'physics jealousy'.

Comment: It's easy for me to treat the phrase as an idiom, e.g, when the meaning of the phrase is not deducible from the individual words (no rules applied) since 'physics' adjective IMHO instead of naming an attribute of a noun (envy) specifies the object for it

Comment: "Physics envy" is likely an application of "penis envy" of Freudian fame.  I would think a good answer would provide some background on that basic use.

Comment: It needs to be noted that the "envy" is of physics itself, since it had a precision and degree of determinism (save for the cat) that other disciplines lack.